# How to use require for organizing my code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm building my cloud code and in need of organizing it. For example I want to move a bunch of methods to a `util.js` file. So I did, and made sure to deploy it. It's definitely on the cloud for my app.

The question is how to use it? I tried putting

```
require('cloud/util.js');
```

at the top of my `main.js` class, and calling the `filter` method within it, but I get a `filter is not defined` error.

The same thing happens when I try this:

```
var util = require('cloud/util.js');
```

either at the top of the `main.js`, or inside my cloud method.

I also tried calling the filter method like this:

```
util.filter(...)
```

but I get a `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'filter'`

So what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main.js` you'll probably just want to require Cloud Functions. Utility and service objects like `util.js` don't need to be there.

In `main.js` you can use the `require('cloud/someCloudFunction.js')` pattern by itself.

But in other files, if you want to require an object, your `var util = require('cloud/util.js')` pattern is correct. But make sure you're exporting the filter function from inside `util.js` correctly.

For example, in `utils.js`, you should have something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  filter: function(something) {
    /* filter something */
  },
  sort: function(something) {
    /* sort something */
  },
  dynamicSort: function(something) {
    /* dynamic sort something */
  }
}
```

Now the filter function should be available as a property of your `util` variable.

Comment: and how would I do it for multiple functions? i.e. "filter", "sort", dynamicSort".

Comment: @Eddy you'd add the methods to the exported `util` module, see my edit.

Comment: Instead of `module.exports`, you simply have to use `exports` for normal functions.
Also cloud functions need not be there in main.js too. You can put them in any file and call `require('cloud/myfile.js');`

Comment: @MKSafi looks like I'm making progress but now when I want to reference dynamicSort from within the util.js file, I'm getting a ReferenceError: dynamicSort is not defined error. I tried calling this.dynamicSort, and util.dynamicSort, but the result is the same. Thanks for hanging in with me.

Comment: So I copied the entire dynamicSort function out of the module.exports, and now it's working. But now I have two duplicates of the same method, which is insane!!! Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

First go through some basics on using require with backbone.

Then go through this

1. [backbone require boilerplate video](http://gregfranko.com/blog/backbone-require-boilerplate-explained/)
2. [explains the code in above video](http://gregfranko.com/blog/using-backbone-dot-js-with-require-dot-js/)
3. http://ozkatz.github.io/converting-an-existing-backbonejs-project-to-requirejs.html
4. http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/re-learning-backbone-js-require-js-and-amd/

Comment: If you want complete code examples on how to structure your application using backbone adn require :http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/
If you want to know about requireJS :firstOne 
http://jsfiddle.net/NssGv/52/
SecondOne
http://jsfiddle.net/4Y4qM/10/